# Straightening Theorem for Vector Fields

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$. The [straightening theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightening_theorem_for_vector_fields) says:

> If $X_p\neq 0$, there is a chart $(U,y_1,...,y_n)$ around $p$ for which $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}$.

The link above gives a proof  using a differential equation argument, but I've tried an alternative proof:

> Take a chart $(U,\phi)$ around $p$ with $U$ small enough so that $X|_U$ is never zero. In that neighbourhood, we can take a smooth local frame $\{X_1,...,X_n\}$, with $X_1=X$. Then:
>   $$X_j=\sum_{i=1}^na_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_i}$$
>   for some $a_{ij}\in C^\infty(U)$. Since $X_1,...,X_n$ are linearly independent, the matrix $(a_{ij})_{i,j}$ is invertible in $U$. In the domain $U$, define: 
>   $$\psi:=(a_{ij})_{i,j}^{-1}\circ\phi$$
>   This function belongs to the maximal atlas, because for every $(V,\xi)$ with $U\cap V\neq \emptyset$, we have:
>   $$\psi\circ\xi^{-1}=(a_{ij})_{i,j}^{-1}\circ(\phi\circ\xi^{-1})\in C^{\infty}$$
>   $$\xi\circ\psi^{-1}=(\xi\circ\phi^{-1})\circ(a_{ij})_{i,j}\in C^{\infty}$$
>   Therefore $(U,\psi)$ is a chart which in particular satisfies $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial \psi_1}$.$_\blacksquare$

I can't see any mistake in this proof, but I've discovered some problems as a consequence of what I did. Using the same idea, if we have fields $X,Y$ which are not zero and linearly independent in some neighbourhood, then we could extend them to a local frame $\{X_1=X,X_2=Y,...,X_n\}$ and construct a similar $\psi$ for which $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial \psi_1},Y=\frac{\partial}{\partial \psi_2}$, but I've read that this is not possible, at least not for arbitrary $X,Y$.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just to add to user7530's answer, a quick reality check: if the $a_{ij}$ were all constant, then we would have $[X_i,X_j]=0$ and the conclusion would follow from the Frobenius Theorem (which if I recall correctly, can be proven by induction using the straightening theorem - see Warner).

Comment: @rmdmc89: This is actually a great question to check your understanding of all the concepts involved. I don't want to spoil it, but let me ask you this: You write $\psi := (a_{ij})^{-1} \circ \phi$. Note that this expression doesn't compile. Let's write $A = (a_{ij})$. Each $a_{ij}$ is a smooth real function on $U$ so $A,A^{-1} \colon U \rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $\phi \colon U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ so you can't really compose them. What you probably mean is to define $\psi$ as $\psi(q) = A^{-1}(q) \cdot \phi(q)$ where the $\cdot$ means matrix multiplication and you treat $\phi(q)$

Comment: as a column vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you do that, note that it's not even clear that $\psi$ is a chart (why should it be a diffeomorphism?). Try to calculate the differential of $\psi(q)$ and see what you get.

Comment: @levap, of course, it seems very obvious now!

Comment: @IvoTerek thanks for that!

Comment: @IvoTerek  just to clarify, the $y_{1} \ldots y_{n}$ is a basis in the state space  $M$?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. The $y_i$ are going to be coordinate functions on some open subset of $M$ and I don't know what you mean by "state space".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything is fine up until the last sentence: "which in particular satisfies $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial \psi_i}$." This would be true if the matrix $a$ were constant over $U\cap V$; generally it's not, and so you are missing chain rule terms that appear when you try to relate the vector fields $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_i}\right\}$ to $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial \psi_i}\right\}$.